# Nondimensionalization of the logistic equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, bifurcation, nonlinear-dynamics

In the process of studying nonlinear dynamics by Strogatz, I saw how he did simplify the model for an insect outbreak with the use of nondimensionalization. So as an exercise I picked an equation and tried to nondimensionalize it. That equation happened to be the logistic equation for population growth.

Here is logistic equation for population gowth with two parameters $R$ and $K$:

$\frac{dN}{dt} = RN(1-\frac{N}{K})$, and

Here is the process by which I nondimensionalized it:

I defined $\tilde N = \frac{N}{N_s}$ and $\tilde t = \frac{t}{t_s}$. Therefore $N = N_s\tilde N$ and $t = t_s\tilde t$.

Now substituting the new variables for $N$ and $t$ we get:

$$\frac{N_s}{t_s}\frac{d\tilde N}{d\tilde t} = RN_s\tilde N(1-\frac{N_s\tilde N}{K}) = RN_s\tilde N - \frac{R{N_s}^2\tilde N^2}{K} \Rightarrow$$

$$\frac{d\tilde N}{d\tilde t} = Rt_s\tilde N - \frac{Rt_sN_s\tilde N^2}{K}.$$

Now we let $Rt_s = 1$ and therefore $t_s=\frac{1}{R}$. We also let $\frac{Rt_sN_s}{K}=1$ and therefore $N_s = K$. Substituting the new values for $t_s$ and $N_s$ we get:

$$\frac{d\tilde N}{d\tilde t} = \tilde N - \tilde N^2.$$

In the resulting equation from nondimensionaliztion there are no parameters. So here are my questions:

1. Did I do it correctly?
2. If I did, since there are no parameters, how am I supposed to analyze the resulting equation which is simply a $2D$ curve?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've imposed $t_s=R^{-1},\,N_s=K$; that's fine. What you need to do next is work out how $\tilde{N}$ varies with $t$. You should find a constant $\tilde{t}_0$ exists for which $\tilde{t}-\tilde{t}_0=\frac{1}{1+\exp -\tilde{N}}$.

Comment: Could you please explain more?

Comment: @Heptapod Which part is unclear?

Comment: I see that I need to work out how $\tilde N$ varies with t, but am not able to see how finding that constant would help it. I am self-studying and new to these concepts so pardon my naiveté.

Comment: @Heptapod You can't find $\tilde{t}_0$; literally any finite value for it is consistent with the problem. You can, however, express it in terms of the $t=0$ value of $\tilde{N}$ if you like. Then, of course, you can rewrite everything in terms of the problem's original variables. I only stated the solution, in which $-\tilde{t}_0$ is an integration constant, so you'll know if you've solved the differential equation properly.

Comment: So I guess the best way to do a simple bifurcation analysis for that equation would be not to nondimensionalize it. Am I correct?

Comment: @Heptapod Actually, you were very wise to nondimensionalise. Sure, you could have studied the solutions without doing so. But your efforts have proven that, no matter what values the parameters take, the problem is exactly the same, up to a linear transformation in $N,\,t$. It's analogous (related, in fact) to their being "only one quadratic" (i.e. $y=ax^2+bx+c$ is, up to linear transformations in both variables, really just the same $y=x^2$ story every time).

Comment: Wow, I didn't consider that. It's clear to me now. Thank you very much.